# Convert vector points to raster using minimum method in Python

Tags: python, raster, gdal, point

I have a large dataset containing over 10 million vector points

I am looking for a way to create a clear and accurate raster in Python by converting the vector points to a raster using the Minimum value.

I've tried `gdal_grid` but unfortunately it is too slow (can take 8+ hours) to create a raster. - Using GDAL Version 3.4.0

Can anyone advise quicker/reliable modules to try?

Comment: This pull request is merged into GDAL master two hours ago from now https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/pull/5397#event-6456166982. I suggest to have a try with it.

Comment: @user30184 I'm afraid I'm abit lost as to what's going on in that pull request

Comment: It makes all methods, including "min", to utilize a spatial index for selecting the points that will be used for interpolation. It should make "min" about as fast as the "nearest". If you cannot test the development version of GDAL you should get an estimate about the speed by using "nearest" instead of "min" with your current GDAL version at least if it is relatively new. It would be good to mention the version also in your question. Generally speaking if you have huge amounts of points maybe you could find some suitable tool from point cloud programs.